# Querying instance details long after it is terminated

Tags: amazon-ec2

In Amazon-ec2, the *instances* page shows details of a machine like its IP, size, key-pair, security group, how long it has run etc.

once the instance is terminated, the line-item stays visible for about an hour. within this period, we can know the details of the machine as it was while running. but once the line item gets removed, there is no way to know that.

say, some instances are manually instantiated, used for some time and then terminated. after an hour of that event there is no way to find out what happened.

there is one detailed-bill feature, but it only provides the instance-ids and size. i am interested in key-pair, ip, OS, security group and name-of-machine if any. is there any way to find out them?

### Edit

I understand that i can have a cron job periodically list all instances (and its details) and store it in a database. thing is, to host that cron process, i would need a machine 24x7. what i need is sort of hook, a callback, event.

even if not readily available, can such a solution be made?

Answer (score 0):

Once the instance has been terminated, like you mentioned, most of the information will be available through the API before it completely disappears after an hour or so. (IP address an DNS will not be available since every time you stop or terminate an instance the IP address is relinquished)  After the instance completely disappears it means that it's gone for good.

The workaround is to query the instances API every so ofter and save the state and instance information. You can save it in memory, a database or just text files, depending on what you are trying to do or what application you are trying to create.

Here's an example of saving the instance information into a Python dictionary in memory using the [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/) Python interface to the API:

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for res in reservations:
    instance = res.instances[0]
    if instance.id == 'i-xxxxxx':
        instance_dict[instance.id] = instance
```

The dictionary instance_dict will always have the IP address, DNS and other instance info for the duration of your program as long as you don't overwrite it. To terminate the instance you can run something like:

```
instance_dict['i-xxxxxx'].terminate()
```

but later you can still use:

```
instance_dict['i-xxxxxx'].ip_address
```

and:

```
instance_dict['i-xxxxxx'].dns_name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Rico, but for this to work, i would need an instance 24x7. micro would do, but it would exist and accumulate costs. any event, callback, notification even logs would do. but does that exist?